# Gauss Seidel Method

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra, gaussian

I wrote a Gauss-Seidel method to calculate the unknown x values of a matrix A. Another methods online seemed to check first if the determinant contains non-zeroes, but other algorithms, including my prof's notes, don't have the verification check.

So I just followed the algorithm that my professor gave in class for now, and I think that the first xNew is correct, because I verified it on my calculator, but my other x values are not updating, can anyone see why?

```
public static void gaussSeidel(double[][] A, double[] b){
int count = 0;
boolean stop = false;

do{
  double[] xNew = new double[b.length]; // x2 = 0, x3 = 0,
  double[] xOld = new double[b.length]; 

  for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){ 
    double sum = 0.0;
    double sum1 = 0.0;
    for(int j = 0; j < A.length; j++){

      if( j != i)
        sum += (A[i][j]*xOld[j]);

     sum1 += (A[i][j]*xNew[j]);
    }

    xNew[i] = (b[i] - sum - sum1)*(1/A[i][i]);
    System.out.println("X_" + (i+1) + ": " + xNew[i]);
    System.out.println("Error is: " + Math.abs((xNew[i] - xOld[i])));
    System.out.println("");
    count++;

    if(Math.abs(xNew[i] - xOld[i]) > EPSILON){
      xNew[i] = xOld[i];
      }

    else{
      stop = true;}   
  }
}while( !stop && count <= MAX_ITERATIONS);
}
```

My matrix:
      `double[][] a = {{12,-2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
{-2,12,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {1,-2,12,-2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,1,-2,12,-2,1,0,0,0,0,0}, 
{0,0,1,-2,12,2,1,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,1,-2,12,-2,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,1,-2,12,-2,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,-2,12,-2,1,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-2,12,-2,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-2,12,0}};`

My b values:

`double[] b = {13.97, 5.93, -6.02, 8.32, -23.75, 28.45, -8.9, -10.5, 10.34, -38.74};`

Comment: which other x values? can you be more specific? also can you post an example with a small matrix so we can test any proposed solution?

Comment: @I.K., I have a 10-by-10 matrix with the given values, so based on the algorithm, the "old values: x_2, x_3, ..." should initially be 0, that's how I know that x_1 should be ~1.16416667, for the first iteration. But this value should change with each iteration until its error is less than epsilon, which isn't happening. That's what I meant, but I'll post both `double[][]a` and `double[]b`. Any suggestions would help!

Comment: it looks like you are trashing your matrix after each iteration.

Comment: @I.K., what does that mean exactly? Like I'm over-riding it?

Comment: Yes. I have posted my suggestion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you loop, you are creating the following arrays again and again:

```
  double[] xNew = new double[b.length]; // x2 = 0, x3 = 0,
  double[] xOld = new double[b.length];
```

Surely, you are loosing the values that you have computed in the previous loop. I would think that you would only need to create these once, so outside of your loop as follows:

```
public static void gaussSeidel(double[][] A, double[] b){
int count = 0;
boolean stop = false;

double[] xNew = new double[b.length]; // x2 = 0, x3 = 0,
double[] xOld = new double[b.length]; 

do{

  for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){ 
    double sum = 0.0;
    double sum1 = 0.0;
    for(int j = 0; j < A.length; j++){

      if( j != i)
        sum += (A[i][j]*xOld[j]);

     sum1 += (A[i][j]*xNew[j]);
    }

    xNew[i] = (b[i] - sum - sum1)*(1/A[i][i]);
    System.out.println("X_" + (i+1) + ": " + xNew[i]);
    System.out.println("Error is: " + Math.abs((xNew[i] - xOld[i])));
    System.out.println("");
    count++;

    if(Math.abs(xNew[i] - xOld[i]) > EPSILON){
      xNew[i] = xOld[i];
      }

    else{
      stop = true;}   
  }
}while( !stop && count <= MAX_ITERATIONS);
}
```

Comment: Yes of course!! But even when I removed it from the do-while loop, my x-values aren't updating as they should, so I realize that this is probably just one of my many bugs.

Comment: Yes. You have a good platform now to move on to correct the other bugs. That `i` variable in the for loop which you are using to index the `b` array looks **very** suspicious. You could potentially end up with a situation where you try to index 'beyond' the array which will cause your program to crash.